# Post based slider in slider revolution

Tags: wordpress

Am having problems to display different categories of post for different titles I have added. I have added 2 posts but in my WordPress, one under category of news and the other one under the category on Notices. but in my slider it is displaying one posts for different titles I have added

I tried to select posts instead of specific post on the content and I selected different categories of posts (News and Notices) but the problem still continued